# Ubuntu 22.04: bluetooth headset non working after autoconnect

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, headset

I am going to describe my issue:

1. I am on Ubuntu 22.04 (OS).
2. I own a bluetooth headset (HS).
3. The HS is paired with OS.
4. I pull HS from its charging shell and it auto connectes to OS.
5. OS shows me the connected HS.
6. I play some music or video, but the audio go through the PC speakers.
7. I manually disconnect HS and manually reconnect it.
8. Now the audio goes through the HS.

Could somebody tell me how to solve it?

Thak you so much!